# Getting the 5 most occuring elements in a nested list (of strings) with collections.Counter

Tags: python, list, nested, counter, element

i have a list like this

```
L = [['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'],
 ['16.37.456.153','119.222.123.112','56388','161','17','62','4646'],..]
```

And i want to get the 5 most occuring elements of that list with collections.counter.

When i use this solution:

```
mostfrequentelements, counterofelements = zip(*Counter(L).most_common(5))
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hypergraph.py", line 65, in <module>
    mostfrequent, countermfi = zip(*Counter(L).most_common(5)) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 477, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 567, in update
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can i use it for my type of list? I need a solution with optimal time complexity.

Input:

```
L = [['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'],
     ['16.37.456.153','119.222.123.112','56388','161','17','62','4646'],..]
```

Output:

```
Mostfrequentlelements = list of 5 most occuring sublists
Counter = list of the occurence counts of the 5 sublists
```

Thank you in advance,
Greetings :)

Comment: If you want to use the lists as keys, you'll have to cast them to an immutable type.  For instance, make them tuples:  `L = [tuple(z) for z in L]`.  This gives you a list of tuples, and you should be fine.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your latest output.

Comment: @Prune Nice thank you :), that worked like a charm. And the runtime seems much better than if i would iterate over the list with L.count.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for a full explanation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a nested list instead of a sequence. You need to access each list in your list `L` before using the counter.

You can create a list of counters and get the values later.

```
L = [['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'],
 ['16.37.456.153','119.222.123.112','56388','161','17','62','4646']]

from collections import Counter

c = [Counter(i) for i in L]

for item in c:
    print(item.most_common(5))
```

**Update**

To count each list, you can join them to string and count them:

```
L = [['16.37.123.153','119.222.456.130','38673','161','17','62','4646'],
 ['16.37.456.153','119.222.123.112','56388','161','17','62','4646']]

from collections import Counter

L = [','.join(i) for i in L]
c = Counter(L).most_common(5)

Mostfrequentlelements = [i[0] for i in c]
Counts = [i[1] for i in c]
```